# Google Spreadsheet: SQL query to add more rows

Tags: sql, google-sheets

If I want to use a sql query to import around 2000 rows from the original google spreadsheet to another one. I will first have to manually keep adding/increasing the number of rows first in the sheet before I attempt to import the 2000 rows.

Example sql query,

=QUERY('Experts'!A:Z,"Select A,C,M   where M <=date """&text(H3,"yyyy-mm-dd")&""" and L='Yes'  ")

Is there anyway for me to be able to use this query directly without first having to manually increase the number of rows to accommodate the imported data?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to manually add rows, the query function will do it for you.